# Which series of digits can't appear in $n!$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Is it true that given a series of digits there always exists an $n$ where $n!$ contains that series of digits?

Comment: Just to clarify: by "series of digits" do you mean a finite sequence of digits $(a_1,\ldots,a_m)$?

Comment: Is there any reason you have to suspect that this would be true? One can ask the exact same question about any sequence. The answer is usually either no, or we don't know.

Comment: Also, do you mean contain exactly (as a substring, say) or do you just want your digits to appear in that order in $n!$ but might be non-consecutive (like $(4,3,2)$ appearing in the number $40320=8!$)? I assume the former.

Comment: @parsiad yes, finite sequence, sorry, my English is not always correct. And yes, substring like.

Comment: @chx: I think Mathmo123's question is also interesting; do you have a reason for suspecting this to be true? (Perhaps you have some insight you can share with potential answerers).

Comment: Not really. Obviously it's true any sequence of zeroes will eventually be found (as trailing zeroes) but nothing more than that.